# Sencha Support for Optional Chaining

Tags: javascript, extjs, optional-chaining

Does Sencha plan to support optional chaining? Or does Sencha already support it and perhaps I'm missing a setting to make it work?

Answer (score 4):

Optional chaining is a feature introduced in ES2020. Assuming your question is Sencha Cmd related, there is a setting ["language"](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.5.1/api/Cmd.codebase.json.Language.html) that you can customize in your `app.json`. But [it seems](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.5.1/api/Cmd.codebase.json.Language.html#cfg-output) for "input" you can only specify a value up to "ES8" (aka ES2017).

So no, unfortunately it is not supported yet. With the slow pace the things are moving in the Sencha space these days, I don't expect it to land anytime soon. Hopefully I am wrong.